# Inbox Zero Tool

Tags: android, email, productivity, imap

I am searching a tool to help me to get "inbox zero" for my mails.

#### What I mean with inbox zero

With "inbox zero" I mean that I am able to handle all mails for one day.

I look at one single mail after the other. I don't look at several mails (subjects/senders) at once.

Looking at the mail I want to have these options:

- archive it
- delete it
- reply or forward
- resubmissing/snoozing (N days later).
- attach a note (text) to the mail

After the decision was made the next mail gets shown.

### Wanted features:

- Re-submission of mails should be easy: *+Nx* (see below)
- Connect to IMAP mail server (I use Dovecot)
- Tool should be running on Android and Ubuntu Linux
- commercial services are ok. It should cost less than 10$ per month.
- Keyboard only support: I want to be able to do the above options with the keyboard (archive, delete, reply, snooze (including timedelta)) ... if there is a desktop version of this tool.

### resubmission/snoozing

Like gmail snooze feature: If you use this feature, the mail should be not visible in the inbox, except you search for mails.

### +N spec

This is optional, but a simple way to specify a duration. Other ways to specify a duration are welcome.

+Nx spec: N is a number. And x can be "d" for "days", "w" for "weeks" and "m" for months. "d" is optional, since it is the default.

Example: +1 means: hide the message for today, show it again tomorrow. +31 means "hide this message 31 days". +12m means "hide this one year"

I explained what I mean with "n days later" here: https://github.com/guettli/n-days-later-method

Comment: I'm afraid such a tool/e-mail client does not exist at the very moment. Or I'm bad at researching.

Comment: @SirMuffington I search a lot, too. Who has time to build new stuff?

Comment: There might be some forums with people looking for new ideas, you should post this idea at such places, I really like the idea of it. I would probably use it instead of my e-mail client tbh, it's a great idea.

Comment: @SirMuffington thank you for the positive feedback. Actually it is not my personal idea. It came from the video (linked at above github page) and the GTD book. IIRC my grandfather worked with the 43 folder system.